# Installing libapache2-mod-fcgid, but can't get through configure

Tags: apt, package-management, apache2, dpkg

I have setup two servers today from a vmware template. One one this worked, the other it didn't. The only difference is that on the failing one I ran `apt-get distupgrades` from the last few days before the command and on the other I didn't. Other than that they are functionally identical. Just on different subnets with different names.

When I run `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-fcgid` I get the following error. I tried running apt-get clean, purge, and autoremove. I'm still getting this error.

```
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-fcgid.
(Reading database ... 155482 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mod-fcgid_1%3a2.3.9-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-fcgid (1:2.3.9-1) ...
Setting up libapache2-mod-fcgid (1:2.3.9-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-fcgid (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-fcgid
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried `apt-get install -f`.

```
$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up libapache2-mod-fcgid (1:2.3.9-1) ...
dpkg: error processing package libapache2-mod-fcgid (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libapache2-mod-fcgid
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I've tried `dpkg-reconfigure libapache2-mod-fcgid`

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure libapache2-mod-fcgid
/usr/sbin/dpkg-reconfigure: libapache2-mod-fcgid is broken or not fully installed
```

Any idea how to figure out what is causing the error or get past this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I exactly got the same error today regarding `libapache2-mod-dnssd` package. And I opened this thread for a solution. Finding no possible soultion I tried to reinstall as being said by the error message.

`sudo apt reinstall libapache2-mod-dnssd`

It worked in my scenario. Hope it work for you too ; )

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by disabling the webmin (virtualmin) and apache services and trying the install again. It worked just fine with those two services stopped. I was able to start them back up after the install.

If someone can explain why this was the resolution, I'll gladly give you the credit. I'd guess something with RAM usage, but both machines had the same RAM. Maybe it had something to do with configuration order or something.